# Cannot install Zoom or Webex Meetings: Unsatisfiable dependency libgl1-mesa-glx

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, 21.04

I cannot install any meeting software in Ubuntu 21.04.

I have tried-

- Zoom
- Cisco Webex Meetings

Whenever I try to install any of these, I am shown that I have unmet dependencies.

I have also tried installing Zoom with `gdebi`, but it did not work as well.

If I run-

```bsh
sudo gdebi Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb
```

I get-

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> This package is uninstallable
>
> Dependency is not satisfiable: libgl1-mesa-glx

So, when I try to install it-

```bsh
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

I get-

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source

When I try to install Webex in the same way, same problem-

> This package is uninstallable
>
> Dependency is not satisfiable: libgl1-mesa-glx

Here's what the apt GUI installer shows-

https://i.postimg.cc/mDbNXJMN/MBg-SCz-Fh-QDGV.png

I have reached an impasse. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Try with apt-get instead of apt. Commands --> `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx`. If this does not work, run `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update`. I don`t remember, but one of them worked for me.

Comment: Maybe you're missing some of the repositories. if @Master_Nachi solution didn't work please post the result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @AvestaSabayemoghadam [here](https://pastebin.com/6Ggw6D75) is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @N0rbert , it did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `main` repository. To add it simply run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo apt update
```

after that you should be able to install `libgl1-mesa-glx`

Comment: That totally worked. Thanks.

I have never seen this happen. Any idea why this happened?

Comment: @swift_truth Maybe you have accidentally disabled it from Software & Updates? Nothing else come into my mind.

Comment: Could be the case. Thanks.